# pytest test_contracts.py error: ImportError: cannot import name state_transition

Tags: testing, pyethereum, serpent

I am struggling to set up pyethereum on an old ThinkPad T500 running Ubuntu 16.04 and Python 2.7.11+, following installation instructions [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Serpent) and [here](http://mc2-umd.github.io/ethereumlab/docs/serpent_tutorial.pdf).

When I test the installation with:

```
pyethereum/ethereum/tests$ pytest -m test_contracts.py
```

I get, for example:

```
going into /home/pavel/Ethereum/pyethereum/ethereum/tests
============================  test_db.py  ============================

===========================  test_abi.py  ============================ 
unhandled exception occurred while testing test_abi Traceback (most
recent call last):   File
"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/logilab/common/pytest.py", line 447,
in testfile
    options=self.options, outstream=sys.stderr)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/logilab/common/pytest.py", line 763,
in __init__
    testLoader=NonStrictTestLoader())   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 77, in __init__
    self.module = __import__(module)   File "test_abi.py", line 3, in <module>
    import ethereum.testutils as testutils   File "/home/pavel/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ethereum-1.3.6-py2.7.egg/ethereum/testutils.py",
line 14, in <module>
    from ethereum import state_transition ImportError: cannot import name state_transition
```

There are at least ten other tests that fail, all with same message:

```
 ImportError: cannot import name state_transition
```

I am eager to get started with pyethereum, and would be very grateful for any and all help. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first problem was that I was running an older version of Serpent (v 1.6.7), that still suffered from the bug described [here](https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/1732/serpent-tutorial-needs-update). My second problem was due to a typo in the Serpent tutorial [here](https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/1732/serpent-tutorial-needs-update): to test the installations, the command is

```
python -m pytest test_contracts.py
```

(in the Serpent tutorial, the "-m" was after "pytest", not before it).

I updated my Serpent via

```
sudo pip install --upgrade ethereum-serpent
```

and now all tests complete successfully.